# How to <mark> code fragments in org-export

Tags: org-mode, org-export

In this HTML source:

```
<html>
  <head>
<title>mark test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>mark test</h1>
<pre>
  <code data-trim>
    def add(a,b):
        <mark>return</mark> a+b
  </code>
</pre>

</body>
</html>
```

`<mark>` is used to highlight some of the content of the `<pre><code>` block. The marked code is highlighted by being rendered in a different style.

How can something similar be achieved with org export to HTML in `SRC` and `EXAMPLE` blocks?

The following *naive* attempt **does not work**:

```
* Code

#+BEGIN_SRC python
  def fib(n):
      if n < 2:
          <mark>return</mark> 1
      return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
  def fib(n):
      if n < 2:
          <mark>return</mark> 1
      return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

[Bonus question: is there an HTML-independent way of highlighting parts of `SRC` and `EXAMPLE` blocks?]

Edit: as [discussed in Picaud Vincent's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/36506/13168) the `ref` mechanism doesn't do the job, because of the requirements:

- the highlight must be visible without the reader's intervention,
- it must be possible to highlight *portions* of lines, not just entire lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is something the export filter functions are particularly suited
for, because they kick in after `htmlize`. See `(info "(org) Advanced configuration")`.

```el
(defun org-html-add-mark-tag (src backend _info)
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
    (replace-regexp-in-string "{{{\\([^\n]+\\)}}}" "<mark>\\1</mark>" src)))
(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-src-block-functions 'org-html-add-mark-tag)
```

```py
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        {{{return}}} 1 
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Comment: Very nice. I wouldn't be surprised if there are other mechanisms, and I wouldn't mind hearing about them, so I'll hold off accepting this answer for a little while. But this certainly points to a way of creating a very decent solution to my problem.

Comment: Might you know how to make the idea work with [org reveal](https://github.com/yjwen/org-reveal)? `org-reveal-src-block` seems to throw some spanner into the works for source blocks, and it's not clear to me how to work around it.

Comment: ... this seems to happen when `use-highlight` in non-`nil` (which seems to be a consequence of `#+REVEAL_PLUGINS: (highlight)` which I *would* like to use). The relevant branch appears to neutralize `#'org-html-htmlize-region-for-paste` by temporarily replacing it with `#'buffer-substring` ... but It's not clear to me where to go from there.

Comment: I'm not familiar with org-reveal, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can use http://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-examples.html for code block, but this is at the best only a partial answer to your question.
I am not aware of such equivalent for `BEGIN_EXAMPLE ... END_EXAMPLE` block.

**Code line highlight example**:

If you html-export this org mode example, the `return 1` line will be automatically highlighted if your cursor is over the "use the link". Moreover, you will jump to the code line if you click on it.

```
#+TITLE: Highlight

#+BEGIN_SRC python -n -r
  def fib(n):
      if n < 2:
          return 1                                                (ref:my link)
      return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
#+END_SRC

Now you can [[(my link)][use the link]].
```

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned up-front why this doesn't satisfy my requirements: a) I need the highlight without any intervention on the reader's behalf, while this requires hovering over the relevant line; b) I need to be able to highlight **portions** of a line while this highlights entire lines.

Comment: @jacg no needs for apologies, writing my answer I feared that your real requirements were those you described in your comment. Unfortunately, I do not know how to do that. Maybe an alternative idea is to build your code incrementally  http://orgmode.org/manual/noweb_002dref.html#noweb_002dref . This let you the opportunity to detail important parts.